Can we have reliable deterministic reasoning processes if our universe is fundamentally non-deterministic?
I asked Would all disagreements vanish if everyone had access to the same information and followed the same reasoning process?. This answer I received challenged the framing of my question, stating:

Our world is not deterministic, so while the theoretical answer is a trivial yes, the actual answer is to reject the premises.

Further elaboration in the comments followed:

Me: Can you please elaborate more? How do you know the world is not deterministic? What facts + what reasoning process led you to that conclusion? And why would that prevent the existence of deterministic reasoning processes? Are theorems in math non-deterministic? How do you reconcile your answer with math?


Him: Because it is quantum based, and those are inherently non-deterministic.


Me: https://www.reddit.com/r/AskPhysics/comments/m9ayzq/can_quantum_mechanics_be_deterministic/?rdt=57054


Him: The internet must be right, true ;-). And actually, the majority on that page seems to agree on "deterministic probability", which is not the same as "deterministic"! Thinking that we have reached the end of knowable things would be absurd, hence the possibility exists that we'll discover truly deterministic, hitherto hidden laws in the future. But we have to base our arguments on something which is the current established science, and that is unequivocal: Nature as we know it is non-deterministic.


Me: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/63811


Him: And to me that underlying fuzziness, even if unintuitive at first glance, makes a lot of sense because a deterministic nature like Laplace envisioned would need infinite information (because all physical values like velocity and location and mass etc. would need to be infinitely precise) in a finite space (e.g, for every atom). That seems like an impossibility; the fuzziness permits the information held per spacetime volume to be finite, and that makes a lot of sense. The imprecise information then causes "imprecise" outcomes.
I don't want to drag this on too much but no true scotsman scientist would pretend to be able to predict events on the quantum level. "Deterministic probability" is the case for any coin toss (predictably 50%); but that's not deterministic. Some say "Undecided"; but that's rather "I am not convinced that the available evidence is all there is". All available evidence is that quantum events are probabilistic, i.e., contain a random element, i.e. are non-deterministic. Yes, as long as nothing "happens" the probability (!) wave function is deterministic....


If the answerer is right and our universe is indeed non-deterministic at the fundamental level, does it follow that the entire pursuit of a reliable deterministic reasoning algorithm is fundamentally flawed from the outset?

Just because the universe is nondeterministic at the quantum level doesn't imply that there are no deterministic processes that go on. It only means that there are no perfectly reliable deterministic processes that can predicted with probability 1.

Deterministic algorithm of any kind is an abstraction, whether the universe is deterministic or not is completely irrelevant to its existence or non-existence. Mathematical circles do not cease to exist just because we cannot draw them with pencils. And electronic computers testify to the fact that deterministic algorithms can be physically implemented and reliably enough for all practical purposes. This is because disturbances can be suppressed by screening, feedback loops and other mechanisms, and it has nothing to do with whether the universe is indeterministic at the fundamental level.

Please cut the quoted discussion from the question, just ask the question as if that chat never happened. It is annoying to read and likely not helpful for indexing the question in search.

@DavidGudeman Sorry to say: Probability 1 is the definition of deterministic.

Your first few quoted paragraphs can be replaced with this answer from Physics SE. The evidence is overwhelming that we are either indeterminate or superdetermined, and there's zero evidence in favor of superdeterminism as well as a jaw-droppingly-unlikely coincidence (the spin-statistics theorem) that the superdeterminist can't explain away.

Just as a side note: we don't know whether the universe is deterministic at the lowest level or not, or what quality the perceived randomness of quantum processes have. We are only sure that our particular quantum theories we have right now match our experiments as close as we can perceive.
Until we know better, and unless/until we find out how random the universe really is (assuming that will ever be possible for us as being part of the same universe), the way out is always to reason not in absolute terms (black and white), but in greyscales. This is already par of the course in many fields; i.e. any real world mechanical engineer will tell you that you cannot do any measurement or calculation with just a single number; you always have to specify the confidence interval as well. All numbers in engineering are always "nominal" with an implied or explicit error margin.
The same goes for any other science. Kepler was perfectly fine and correct on his level of observation – when squinting quite a bit, you don't "need" Einstein to argue about the approximate workings of our solar system. You only need to add a caveat to each calculation about how closely it would match observation, and a way to properly calculate with those ranges of correctness propagate through further calculations. You don't need to step down to the quantum realm to encounter this for the first time.
Any Computer Science student will tell you how the way reals are represented in a computer is always just a rough approximation, but somehow it works out just fine for 99.999% of cases. A real number stored in a computer will be representing a small (sometimes not so small) interval instead.
That said,  big parts of quantum theories are about how to transform arguably random processes into expected outcomes with acceptable, low margins of error. Yes, all the atoms in the underwear of the beautiful party host or hostess can decide to take a step to the left at the same time, but it is sufficiently unlikely not to worry.

If the answerer is right and our universe is indeed non-deterministic at the fundamental level, does it follow that the entire pursuit of a reliable deterministic reasoning algorithm is fundamentally flawed from the outset?

The universe is the reliable algorithm! If you wish to know what our solar system is doing in one million years from now, you only need to be around at that time and witness it. It does not matter whether the universe is really random at its lowest level or whether it just has enough hidden variables so we can never get down to the non-random parts of it.
And if and when we figure out that the universe is non-random, and we figure out the "algorithm" completely and correctly, it's still a moot point, because we can do nothing with the information - we will not be able to build a computer that calculates all of this information directly (without, again, subsuming large swaths of information into more abstract, intermediate information packages if you so like, which again equates error margins like explained above) simply because said computer would be part of the same universe it is calculating. And if we want to actually get at the output of the computer, that is equivalent with the fact that there would be reciprocal action between the computer and the outer universe – the computer output would be part of causal chains outside itself. So the computer would have to include itself in its calculation. There will never, out of principle, be such a thing; it would just be eternal recursion.
Oh and also, N.B., the question of whether the universe is truly random at the lowest level is quite different from whether it is deterministic. Being truly random is equivalent with "we don't know the algorithm or all the information". Being indeterministic would be equivalent with "if we roll back the whole universe to a previous point in time, the new evolution of the universe could differ from the first one". While one may argue that one option for the one question might influence the other, they are still different concepts.
To get at practical or meaningful questions about determinism, you do not need to know these weird things about the universe. You can safely assume a modicum of randomness muddled with hidden variables, missing information and unknown algorithms, and go on with that. Quantum-or-not is just a little implementation detail.

This. Reality is fuzzy, fractal, or both. Except as a thought experiment or a convenient approximation, absolutes are purely theoretical. While it may be an entertaining philosophical exercise to explore the implications if they weren't  (and in some cases that model makes useful predictions), it is a mistake to confuse the model with the thing it models.

@Peter-ReinstateMonica, I have reformulated that paragraph, it's not the most important part of the answer anyways.


Can we have reliable deterministic reasoning processes if our universe is fundamentally non-deterministic?

Yes. Engineering blueprints are an example of a document that describes how to build an object in a deterministic manner that allows for the inherent indeterminism that is prevalent when performing any measurement.
This is done by including tolerances and uncertainties in all descriptions that involve a measurement.
Since there is no way to construct using perfect measurements, engineers design systems that perform in a nearly deterministic manner within a certain tolerance

NO, we cant have DETERMINISTIC anything but we don't need to!
One can reason successfully without that reasoning being 100% reliable, or deterministic.  The criteria for reasoning success is Darwinian, not absolutist.

IF our universe is mostly stable at the macro scale
AND it mostly is
THEN the criteria for valid reasoning about it only needs to be probably correct.
AND the reasoning we developed IS only probably correct
Therefore the reasoning we have about our world is not "deterministic" reasoning, but is "reliable" reasoning


"No" what? Not non-deterministic?

Obviously you can make predictions about the stable, predictable part of the universe (that's a tautology, isn't it?); but the question was, I believe, more universal, if you allow the pun. The underlying randomness of reality at the micro level eventually manifests itself on the macro level because there are so many non-linear systems (three body problem, for example, or the weather). A storm or drought may decide battles or doom empires and change everything. An asteroid dooms Dinosaurs but lets mammals prevail, leading to us...

@Peter-ReinstateMonica -- life, in particular, consists of bounded chaotic systems.  One tiny gamma ray emitted billions of light years away on just the right trajectory hitting a nucleotide in the wrong spot can dramatically affect the subjects life by inducing cancer.  Chaotic systems leverage quantum indeterminacy up to macro scales.  But linear predictions still work most of the time.

I agree... we can often predict -- until we can't. The first part is your point, the second part is mine. (As a side note, "we scientists", and by association the modern Western world, may in a circular fashion overestimate the predictable things because they are the only things we talk about. Non-reproducible things are simply not scientifically considered. They may be the realm of religion and art and poetry.)

You ask:

Can we have reliable deterministic reasoning processes if our universe is fundamentally non-deterministic?

Yes, and any argument to the contrary runs afoul of the fallacies of composition and division insofar as the properties of the whole universe do not determine the properties of parts of the universe and vice versa. In other words, because the universe is non-deterministic, it does not stand to reason that parts of it cannot be deterministic within parameters to achieve deterministic results.
Quantum mechanics describes an aspect of the universe at the microscopic level, but it does not describe the aspect of the universe at the macroscopic level, and conflating those two levels seriously abuses reason (despite quantum effects that "leak" into the macroscopic realm). For instance, modern personal computers are highly deterministic machines that run highly deterministic algorithms. That is because they are designed with deterministic properties of materials and outcomes in mind. If not, adding 2 and 2 together with an ALU/CU wouldn't produce 4 repeatedly. And where leaks from the microscopic world do occur, such as in soft errors, they can be dealt with by engineering strategy. In fact, engineering is largely the practice of making systems deterministic out of difficult to predict situations.
To see the flaw in the reason more clearly, people are composed of molecules, but the rules that govern molecules (chemistry) do not describe the behavior of people whose thinking is described by and governed by a different set of rules and properties (psychology). In a similar way, relativistic physics governs the motion of bodies with large size and speed which are not described by quantum mechanics. Thus, we have two theoretical frameworks that describe and predict behavior in the universe, the macroscopic (which entails much determinism) and the microscopic, and we apply the appropriate framework. To attribute the properties of one theory to the other neglects our basic mereological ability to abstract to different sorts of contexts, abstractions, and theories.

Paragraph two is bogus; quantum effects can be magnified to macroscopic observations. Even the quantum-computing skeptics surely would admit that cosmic rays affect hardware, and ALUs have been affected in e.g. voting machines and airplane control systems.

Paragraph three is a reach. We can combine relativity and QM in several ways, giving rise to e.g. relativistic QM, which yields the best explanation for the color of gold and also predicts the invisible-to-human colors of platinum and mercury.

@Corbin Exactly: The quantum randomness "leaks" into the macro world. Sometimes slower, sometimes faster.

@Corbin Of course. In computer science, we call them soft errors. No one is saying that quantum tunneling doesn't cause macroscopic effects, but your term "leak" conveys the point precisely; it's a very minor effect. Soft errors can be corrected for, and thus, with some added measure, the system can be made extremely deterministic. I will however, hedge my language since it seems important to note leaks do occur.

@Peter-ReinstateMonica I've edited in language to show how quantum "leakage" is generally dealt with by additional engineering measures. It's a fair riposte to say that the two realms aren't entirely discrete. On the whole, though, chairs don't undergo quantum tunneling, and calculators produce deterministic results. Any fool who believes we are swimming in a sea of quantum uncertainty pays neither death any heed nor taxes. There are many things that are deterministic in the macroscopic realm.

I appreciate both of your quibbles. They certainly have strengthened the response.

@Corbin I've skimmed the relativistic QM article: "In physics, relativistic quantum mechanics (RQM) is any Poincaré covariant formulation of quantum mechanics (QM). This theory is applicable to massive particles propagating at all velocities up to those comparable to the speed of light c, and can accommodate massless particles. The theory has application in high energy physics,[1] particle physics and accelerator physics,[2] as well as atomic physics, chemistry[3] and condensed matter physics." Yeah, these are all microscopic phenomena.

People die all the time from equipment failing or trees falling randomly at precisely a given point in time, and not later or earlier. Sure, chairs are predictable -- until they aren't. Safeguards are obviously only gradual measures and do not change the principles.

@Peter-ReinstateMonica I don't dispute that there can be sensitive dependence on initial conditions, but I don't see how it undermines the thesis that determinism is possible to some degree in the macroscopic world which is why I label the objection a quibble. It doesn't fundamentally undermine the idea that because random phenomena exist in the macroscopic world, calculators are somehow non-deterministic machines. I am interested, however, if you have a reference that defends the thesis that macroscopic randomness is leakage from quantum uncertainty. Do you a reference I might review?

@JD Obviously, a cosmic ray (i.e., a quantum, randomly on a path that intersects with our trajectory through space time) can flip a bit and alter the result of your calculator. And one can surely harvest quantum randomness intentionally, isolating and amplifying the naturally occurring leakage. Such a random number may create a millionaire and thus alter history.


is the pursuit of a reliable deterministic reasoning algorithm is fundamentally flawed

Algorithms are abstract, they can be deterministic, 1+1 is always 2 in algebra. So for theoretical purposes, anyone might pursue this reasonably.
In Body-Mind dualism, mind could also still be fully deterministic (though nobody routs for that approach), and would allow to think fully deterministically.
In physical monism, building a machine that can fully deterministically execute any algorithm in a non-deterministic universe is only possible if all sources of indeterminism can be isolated or ignored. Even in a fully deterministic universe this is a challenge as any material used to build a computer might have physical flaws undetected until it's too late, or unforeseen events might happen influencing the computer and algorithm result. NASA as an example would always try to use multiple redundant systems.
If deterministic outcomes of an algorithm are untrustworthy because of indeterminisn of matter or unforeseen errors, a pragmatic solution is to run the same algorithm with the same input on two different physical machines in different locations and at different times while monitoring for all undue influences. The chance then of random indeterminacy causing the same erroneous result multiple times becomes so unlikely then that for all practical purposes the result can be relied upon (foreign influence such as by a computer virus would still be a threat though).
Note this might be impossible still if any machine running this algorithm can be expected to suffer at least one error due to indeterminisn (or other circumstance). But given today's use of computers, it would seem this universe probably allows building a machine for reasoning that would provide reliable enough results.
In science fiction though we can imagine an algorithm that runs for 1000 years and can only run on one machine and the survival of humanity depends on the exact result, and then it would be a real challenge to consider whether the output can be trusted as correct (or whether engineers can keep such a calculation running without mistakes for that long).

"Deterministic reasoning" sounds a lot like pure logic, where facts inevitably lead to other facts and questions have only one right answer. This has been used successfully as the method to resolve conflicts and disagreements within the society. But in fiction only (The Vulcans in Star Trek).
In reality, that would require suppressing most of the basic things that make us human: emotions, beliefs, opinions and morality. In addition, everyone's cognitive abilities would have to be raised above a certain level to avoid misinterpretations of the common knowledge base.
I would say that a society based on pure logic would be impossible to achieve. Even if it were possible, the price we would have to pay would be too high.
